# Google Maps loaded using API into iframe not displaying in IE

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, iframe, mixed-content

I'm working on an iframe that displays a Google map using the maps API. The iframe is delivered using https as is the Google map. Everything displays correctly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. However in IE, the map doesn't load.

IE is throwing the mixed content warning and says is only displaying the secure content. The odd thing is it's showing all the secure content, *except the Google map*.

**You can see the iframe in action here:
https://auctionlook.com/embed-test/**

*I know there is a lot of elements on the root site that is being loaded on http rather than https but all the content within the iframe is being loaded on https.*

Clicking any of the auction listings, will direct you to the page that loads the Google map that doesn't show in IE.

This is the code for the embed, nothing really special here but wanted to include it just in case.

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="none" src="https://kentuckyauctioneers.org/auction-embed/?embed_id=KY-F2AB892A745D484C920E4137A9C3238B&isembed"></iframe> <script src="https://auctionlook.com/apps/library/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> <script>iFrameResize({ enablePublicMethods: true, sizeHeight: true, checkOrigin: false });</script>
```

An example of the content being loaded within the iframe, with the map, lives here: https://kentuckyauctioneers.org/auction/premium-listing/201504KY-14064/

The map loads fine in IE on the stand alone page, but not within the iframe.

Any guidance offered is welcome.

*For further clarification, I've included screenshot of the map not displaying in IE and displaying correctly in Chrome.*

[image: Map not displaying in IE]

[image: Map displays correctly in Chrome and other browsers]

Comment: huh... it works on my windows 8.1 machine, with IE 11.0.9600.17690..... are you testing it on mobile or desktop, and what version?

Comment: Testing desktop running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IE 11.0.9600.17631.

Comment: I think that might due to the extra security stuff which comes with the windows server.... I would have no idea rather than that

Comment: I'm testing from Windows Server because that's the only Windows machine I currently have available. However I've confirmed with a co-worker outside my office that it is happening for him on IE 11 on Win 7 and 8.1.

Comment: How about this, does this works on your devices? if this works, then there must be something wrong with your container (like a javascript error, so that the map init doesn't get run) http://fiddle.jshell.net/kylelam/pLLec8hL/show/

Comment: also be sure not to use the exp version of the maps api, it is known to have problem with IE

Comment: kaho - thanks for all your help so far; I tried that fiddle in IE 11 and had the same issue with the map not loading. This is certainly a really strange issue. Also, I'm not using the exp version of the maps api.

Answer (score -2):

you can use a proxy look like free gate 790p or earlier, then map is showing on ie, in my opinion that related to proxy setting on ie.